# array_diff() problems with mysqli results and while loop

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to compare 2 arrays and get this error.  Warning: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array.  Not really sure why I get this error a While statement for `sql` results is an array.

Why am I getting this error and how do I correct it?

```
$dataArray = array('234534,345345,445667');

if($arrayCheck = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT FRIEND_ID FROM FRIENDS_DIR WHERE ID=? AND ONLINE=1")){
    $arrayCheck->bind_param('s', $dataA);
    $arrayCheck->execute();
    $arrayCheck->bind_result($FidS);
    $arrayCheck->store_result();
    if($arrayCheck->num_rows > 0){
        while ($arrayCheck->fetch()) {
            if (array_diff($FidS, $dataArray)){
                $res = "NoSame";
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $res;
```

Comment: `$arrayCheck->fetch_assoc()` ?  instead of `fetch()`

Comment: $arrayCheck->fetch_assoc() wont work with prepared statements.  The proper way is $arrayCheck->fetch()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because `$FidS` is not an array but a number or string (depend in your DB table definition).

Notice your `SQL` query returns `FRIEND_ID` and not an array - if you want to use `array_diff` change your code to:

```
if($arrayCheck->num_rows > 0){
    $resSqlData = [];
    while ($arrayCheck->fetch()) {
        $resSqlData[] = $FidS;
    }
    if (array_diff($resSqlData , $dataArray)){
            $res = "NoSame";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im still getting the same error..Warning: array_diff(): Argument #1 is not an array.

Comment: I missed `[]`. Updated